# How to import a directory of excel files into MS ACCESS with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pyodbc, sqlalchemy-access

I have been trying to import multiple files into MS Access with python but keep getting the following error:

DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HYC00', '[HY00] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Optional feature not implemented (106) (SQLBindParameter)')

Here is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa
import openpyxl
from sqlalchemy import *

xls_path = r'C:\Users\JMJ\Desktop\Excel_docs
df = pd.read_excel(xls_path, engine = openpyxl)

connection_string = (r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
                     r'DBQ=C:\Users\JMJ\Desktop\testdb_python.accdb;'
                     r'ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;'
)
connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
     "access+pyodbc",
     query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
df.to_sql('New_table', engine)
```

Does anyone know how to get this code running?

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/%5Bpandas%5D-working-with-64-bit-integer-(BIGINT)-values

Comment: also possibly of interest: https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/%5Bpandas%5D-faster-alternative-to-.to_sql()-for-large-uploads